# IOS SDK: Container view with 3 UI View area how to?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, ipad

I'm newbie in iOS dev. I need windows with tree views on it. I created view-base application, and added UIView controls in master view. Also i added 3 View controllers for that views with view definition in separated xib files. How to link views from separated xib files with view areas on master view? Should i manually create controller instances and load controller's view into view areas? Or maybe is possible to create them in IB? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just drag the instances of the three controllers into the nib file of the master view, and resize them in order to create the desired layout. However, make sure that the properties on the subviews are correct or they could overlap. In the library window of IB, go to the classes tab, and drag the classes you want (View Controllers) to the nib.

I prefer that method over manually adding them through code, as it allows much better functionality with resizing such as from rotation.

Comment: I added View1Controller from classe to main Project controller xib. I have selected NIB Name (View1Controller.xib). What i should do next? Place uiview on master view and link it with controller? or something else? After visual studio, it's hard to understand.

Comment: Add it to the view within the nib file. From here, you can resize it within the view pane itself. The nib file should look like:
    File's Owner        MasterView
    First Responder
    >View
      View1Controller
And then the resizes in the view1controller in the view pane should reflect accurate resizing and placement. In inspector, use the third tab (size inspector) to manage the alignment, origin, and stretch properties of the view.

Comment: Yea, that was my mistake, for some reason I thought you were able to drag the view controllers but you can't add them directly to a view. My best guess to solve this would just be to add the view controllers to the nib, and resize them using viewcontroller.view.frame=*size*. Though I think there is a better way, I just can't find in one of these apps where we did it directly through IB. Keep in mind, as mentioned in the original answer, you need to incorporate something to deal with the resizing of them during a rotation.